Import "cryptography.fernet" could not be resolved
I keep getting the same problem in my code. It says that "Import "cryptography.fernet" could not be resolved". I was following along with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vk4WWIreH8Q. How do you think I should solve this problem?
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
# encryption key
file1 = open("topSecret.key","wb")
file1.write(key)

I tried different Youtube videos and Github accounts. But it is kind of hard for me to find the answers.
